# ¿Alguien sabe por qué no funciona el botón ni me aparecen los toast?

Tags: java, android-studio, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un inicio de sesión con una base de datos pequeña en SQL, utilizando services ya intenté correrlos en el navegador y si me funcionan, pero a la hora de darle el botón no hace nada, ni siquiera muestra los toast. Les agradecería mucho si podrían responderme si tengo algo mal en el código, es mi primera vez preguntando:) gracias. Adjunto código:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edtUsuario=findViewById(R.id.edtUsuario);
    edtUsuario=findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    btnLogin=findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            validarUsuario("http://192.168.0.4:8080/empresa/validar_usuario.php");
        }
    });

}

private void validarUsuario(String URL){
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(!response.isEmpty()){
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PrincipalActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> parametros=new HashMap<String,String>();
            parametros.put("usuario",edtUsuario.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("password",edtPassword.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
```

Comment: En vez de Toast usa el Log cat de Android Studio para depurar tu código. Pon un Log en cada parte con un mensaje, revisa el Log cat y dinos por dónde está entrando tu código.

Comment: Seguramente tienes deshabilitado no se muestren notificaciones en tu dispositivo ya que en este caso o se muestran o se realiza un intent a PrincipalActivity.